# Word for disenfranchising women of their rights to make money

Tags: single-word-requests

Disenfranchising is mostly used for deprivation of voting rights. what I am looking for is a word for depriving women of their right to earn money.

Her husband _____ her, so she is stuck as a housewife.

Comment: [*YouTube **Demonetization** Explained*.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QiNloVVpeCQ) But your example context sounds more like a highly specific form of [chauvinistic] ***persecution, repression, slavery, servitude, vassalage,...*** to me.

Answer (score 1):

Disenfranshise is hardly exclusive to voting rights. “The disenfranchised youth” have the same voting rights as “the enfranchised youth”. Disenfranchisement, according to a dictionary, is the removal of rights, such as civil rights or human rights, both of which are quite applicable to your example. Alienation could as work conceptually, but not in that specific sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If your reputation in a certain industry has been tarnished by others and those who would hire you have been convinced not to, you have been ***"blackballed"***.

Most sources cite the origin of this term from the late 18th c. practice of casting votes in clubs or fraternities with the use of white and black balls.

The common use in Am E is most probably related to the *blackballing* of Hollywood personnel (for communist sympathies) during the infamous Mc Carthy hearings.